# Git can't pull because of uncommited changes, but stashing and applying stash causes no conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, git-stash

I am curious why git complains it can't perform a git pull because there are modified files, but when I stash them away, do a pull and then apply the stash all the files are merged nicely without conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

The `git pull` command is, in effect, just a shortcut for running *two* Git commands.  The two Git commands are, in this order:

1. `git fetch`, and
2. some other Git command: usually `git merge`, but you may choose `git rebase` instead (there's one special case where it's just `git checkout` but this only occurs if you have no commits yet).

That *second* command is the one that requires that the index and working tree be "clean" (contain no uncommitted changes).

The commands you added—`git stash push` (or in older versions of Git, `git stash save`; note that `git stash` means one of those two) before the pull, and `git stash apply` afterward—*can* run in a "non-clean" working tree.  In fact `git stash push` does nothing at all, not creating any stash commits, if everything is completely clean.  The `push`/`save` stash operation works by:

- making two (or sometimes three, but not in this case) commits that are on *no* branch; then
- running (the equivalent of) `git reset --hard`, to throw away unsaved work: this is safe because while it's unsaved in your existing index and/or working tree, it *was* saved by those two commits that it made in the first half of the operation.  One of those two commits saved the state of Git's index, and the other saved the state of your working tree, so now it is safe for `git reset` to reset both Git's index and your working tree.

Having thrown out any unsaved work (after saving it in those "behind the scenes" commits, that are not on *any* branch), everything is now clean.  So `git pull` can proceed: it will do the fetch (which is always possible) and then it will be able to do the merge-or-rebase (which requires the cleanliness it just ensured).

The merge or rebase, as performed by the *second* command, *may* stop in the middle with conflicts.  If this is the case, it becomes your job to help Git complete the operation (finish the merge or rebase).  When you have done that—finished the operation—everything is once again "all clean".  So, *now* it's possible to use `git apply`, or `git apply --index`, whichever you prefer.  This takes the two commits that are on *no* branch and applies one of them (if you run without `--index`) or both of them (`--index`) to the current index and working tree.

Note that modern Git has `--autostash` as an option to `git pull`.  Here, `git pull` does its usual check to see if everything is all clean.  If so, it just does its usual two commands.  If *not*, though, it runs `git stash` *for* you.  Then it runs its usual two commands, and **if they work** (all the way to the end, without stopping in the middle to get help from you to finish), *then* it runs `git stash apply`, and if *that* works, `git stash drop`.

I recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely, which renders the question of whether it's safe to use `--autostash` moot.  The big problem with `--autostash` is that if the merge-or-rebase *stops in the middle*, the `git pull` operation is ended.  You can finish the merge-or-rebase, but now *you* have to deal with the final stash.  Moreover, applying a stash does not always work.  I recommend *avoiding* `git stash` in all but extremely simple cases, because when applying a stash fails, it can be difficult to use the not-on-any-branch commits that `git stash` makes.  I find it better to just make a regular everyday commit.  You can shuffle that commit around later, using all of Git's tools, not just the substandard ones available for stashes.

(There is another way to handle a problematic stash, using `git stash branch`, but that's another topic.)